# Python timeit - TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I usually use timeit in jupyter notebook like this:

```
def some_function():
    for x in range(1000):
    return x

timeit(some_func())
```

and get the result like this:

```
6.3 ms ± 42.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

but today I got an error like this:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-fef6a46355f1> in <module>
----> 1 timeit(some_func())

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

How does it occur?

Comment: I guess you are running `import timeit`, then trying to execute the module. Instead, you should import the function. Changing your import statement to `from timeit import timeit` should fix this.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching and trying for a while I realize that when we want to use `timeit(some_function())`, we do not need `import timeit` but we should write it in another input of jupyter notebook like this:

IN [1]:

```
def some_function():
    for x in range(1000):
    return x
```

IN [2]:

```
timeit(some_func())
```

and we will get output like this:

```
280 ns ± 2.78 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

When we write it in one input like this:

IN [1]:

```
def some_function():
    for x in range(1000):
    return x

timeit(some_func())
```

we'll get an error timeit not define and when we 'import timeit' we'll got another error like I produce on the question `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`.

because when we `import timeit` we need to specify the stmt and setup (if available) e.g:

```
import timeit

SETUP = """
    import yourmodul_here
"""

TEST_CODE = """
    def some_function():
    for x in range(1000):
    return x
"""

timeit.timeit(stmt=TEST_CODE, setup=SETUP, number=2000000)
```

And we'll get the output like this:

```
0.12415042300017376
```

- stmt is code to run
- setup is something that need to load before `TEST_CODE` run
- The stmt will execute as per the number is given here. default = 1000000

so when we import timeit we need to write more I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You are currently trying to execute the `timeit` module, rather than the function contained within.

You should change your import statement from `import timeit` to `from timeit import timeit`. Alternatively, you can call the function using `timeit.timeit`.

Comment: I got another error like this `ValueError: stmt is neither a string nor callable`

Comment: That seems unrelated to the question you posted. I recommend that you have a go at fixing it yourself. If you can't, then please open a new question with the relevant information (error traceback and source code).